# sex spam and offenses of user in my rss feed

Tags: support

just wanted to report this, probably gets deleted here immediately, but is there a way to keep such "questions" spam out of rss feed too, maybe delay time, till questions is added to front page and rss feed. Ironically, this is the first time I see spam in a SE feed/site, wondering how such a popular site managed it to delete all spam so fast, but felt remembered on old usenet days visiting my SE feed today :)

Comment: The management of the RSS feeds is a network-wide issue and would need to be taken up on the mother meta. As you haven't provided any links I have to assume you mean the events of Thursday and Friday. The team had to be called in, and steps were taken at a level where even us puny moderators don't get to know what went on. Hopefully that is the end of it.

Comment: BTW the way these things normally get handled is by spam flags, which anyone can cast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you delayed the appearance of posts, then how could the community review them and take the appropriate action? If nobody sees it, then nobody flags as spam or offensive, and it'll eventually appear anyway, only to *then* be flagged.

Almost all users who saw the question you call "sex spam" (which it wasn't, but that doesn't make it any better) flagged it as offensive, so it was deleted automatically pretty quickly.

The reason that you rarely see something like this on the Stack Exchange sites – despite it being posted; it turns out there are quite a few idiots on the internet – is that the community has the tools to take care of these posts pretty quickly, without having to rely on a moderator being available immediately. The larger the site is (and thus the more crap it attracts), the more people there are that see the post and flag it as offensive, and thus the quicker it gets killed.

On Stack Overflow (which is orders of magnitude larger), a post like the one in question here has a pretty good chance of being deleted in under 60 seconds.

It should be noted that our automatic protection against spam *bots* works pretty well; the problem is actual *humans* littering on the site, and for those, technical solutions obviously only work so far.

On websites that allow user-generated content, we have to live with the fact that stupid people exist; all we can do is make sure the community is able to react quickly. Hiding new posts would be counterproductive to that, in addition to also punishing the vast majority of new posts that are legitimate.

Comment: I often check the SE feed on smartphone in google reader, there is no easy fast way to flag those post, also your site constantly logs me off, when not visiting 2-3 days. Also, I exactly read via rss to not see the spam and all the edit pushs, only new questions. I thought you have automatic spam remover, at least for insulting pattern words and similar

Comment: There are a _very_ few things that are automatically blocked, I believe, but in general, spam control is done by the community using flags, not an automatic system.